# Celery : Execute task after a specific time gap

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I want to send an email to my users exactly 48 hours after they have registered.How do i achieve this using celery? If I create a periodic task to send an email, I will have to decide a specific time during which i want to execute that task. I don't want to keep run a celery task every second to check if there are any emails needed to be sent.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You'll want to make use of [ETA](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown). Read that section of the docs as it'll have more information. However, your code will look something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
send_date = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=2)
email_user.apply_async([user], eta=send_date)
```